# How do PID control loop in a servo motor reverse motor direction?

Tags: motor, servo, pid-controller

Suppose the motor is set to turn to the 40 deg position. We apply a load that acts in the opposite direction (want to take the motor to the 30 deg position). A simple P(ID) controller will apply current proportional to the error. Now the motor is at position 41 deg. Still an error so the controller will reduce the current till a balance is reached.

However, in the opposite case, when the load is trying to turn the motor to the 50 deg position, you actually need to turn the motor in the opposite direction (with the same amount of current as before). But a simple PID loop cannot do that. It can only change the amount of current, but not its polarity. I understand we can somehow imply an H-bridge to reverse polarity but don't see how this is integrated in the system.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you say a PID loop cannot change polarity?  The derivative term can be negative and if it's magnitude exceeds the other terms should result in a negative torque at the motor.

Comment: OK, say its magnitude is now negative. How will the motor reverse? I know we can use H-Bridge but it is not clear how the PIC controller and the H-Bridge are used together.

Comment: You can use an H-bridge but you enable the other diagonally opposite pair of switches and pulse them with PWM.

Comment: I guess this is good enough. If you prefer put this in an answer and I'll close the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the implementation of a PID controller.

[image: pid controller]

The PID controller wants to make its *Error* \$e(t)\$ equal to 0.
Your implementation determines which way the actuator goes.

Take setpoint 40 while actual 0 degree. The Error is 40.
Take kP to be 5, then U will be 40*5 = 200.
Your process, the motor controller, then outputs 200, in positive direction.

But setpoint -40 while actual 0 degree. The Error is -40.
When kP is 5, U will be -40*5 = -200.
Your motor controller then outputs -200, in negative direction.

If you invert this, the PID will output 200, but error will increase. Creating a loop until something clips or breaks.